# Is it possible to order a new Mac mini with an Nvidia graphics card?

Tags: mac-mini

This may be obvious to many , but is it possible to have a current generation Mac Mini with Nvidia graphics card option . I looked into the spec sheet on Apple website which says that it ships with AMD graphics card . I am looking for the one that has Nvidia graphics card.

I've searched over Google and did not find a plausible answer (but I'm a bit rushed and may have mislooked the answer).

Comment: Why do you want an Nvidia graphics card?

Answer (score 3):

No you can't order the current generation [Mac Mini Mid-2011](http://www.everymac.com/ultimate-mac-lookup/?search_keywords=Macmini5,2) with anything other than what Apple will offer to you as a build to order option for graphcis.

**Currently the only options for [graphics on the Mac Mini](http://www.apple.com/macmini/specs.html) are:**

- Intel HD Graphics 3000
- AMD Radeon HD 6630M

Recall from [iFixit's Mac Mini tear down](http://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/Mac-Mini-Mid-2011-Teardown/6131/1) that the Mac Mini is a highly integrated machine, and there really is no such thing as a "graphics card" in it, its a graphics chip set on the motherboard as pictured below from iFixit, what Apple puts on it is what you have to choose from.

[image: There is your Graphics]

However, with the Availability of Thunderbolt there is opportunity for expensive external graphics options on Mac Mini's with Thunderbolt. Products such as the [Sonnet Echo Express](http://www.sonnettech.com/product/echoexpresschassis.html) offer external PCI express x4 speed slots, but as of yet there are not listed graphics card that are compatible.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to purchase a Mac Mini with Nvidia Graphics, you'll have to buy an older one with Core 2 Duo processors.

The current Mac mini with Sandy Bridge Processors (i5, i7) only ships with AMD graphics.

For more information check out Wikipedia's summary of Mac Mini specifications [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_mini#Specifications_3) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_mini#Specifications_2).

Comment: Thanks , it may be offtopic ... is there anything in the PC world equivalent to mac mini having nvidia graphics card . Its just I need a portable nvidia graphics card bundled in a mac mini format for my college course . I need it badly .

Comment: @MotiurRahman I'm not aware of any PC equivalent.

Comment: @MotiurRahman What you're looking for is a [shuttle computer](https://www.google.com/search?q=pc+shuttle&tbm=isch). These aren't sold with OS X, though.